# CPU Usage going high while using XMLReader in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing, large-files, xmlreader

I have an huge xml file(23 GB).While parsing using XMLReader, it takes only little memory, but the **CPU usage is going 100%.**

I am using m3 xlarge machine on AWS. What will be the reason?

Below is the code using for xml parsing.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$items = array();
$xml_url = "/home/test/apparel_mp.xml";
try {
    if (!$reader->open($xml_url)) {
        print "Error to open XML: $xml_url\n";
    } else {
        while ($reader->read()) {
            if ($reader->name == "item_data") {
                $exNode = $reader->expand();
                $node = @simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($exNode, true));
                if (!empty($node)) {
                    $item_product = array();
                    $item_product['source_product_id'] = (string) $node->item_basic_data->item_sku;
                    //$item_product['item_brand'] = (string) $node->item_basic_data->item_brand;
                    $item_product['source_title'] = $item_product['title'] = (string) $node->item_basic_data->item_name;
                    $items[] = $item_product;
                }
            }
        }
        $reader->close();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

Is it because of simplexml_import_dom function?

Comment: If you have a simple question like this, you are probably the only person who can easily answer it. Remove the `simplexml_import_dom()` function, run the code again, and you will have your answer. Test again with other bits removed, or added. We cannot do this for your. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to figure out why we cannot verify your problem.

Comment: issue got solved by adding one second delay in while loop.